# compiling i8ukutils 1.42 for kernel 3.16

Tags: debian, compiling

I am trying to run i8k on my Debian with linux 3.16 (amd64),

I have deb from repository (1.41), and the service is starting, i8kmon is showing correct stats, but fan control is not working,
and what I think is the issue, there is no smm in the system. the ./smm-test script throws 'theres no smm program'.

I know the last i8kutils 1.43 does not include smm, as of recent changes in the kernel 4.*, but 1.41 (from repo), and 1.42 should be okey with my 3.16 kernel. So why there's no smm file in the repo package?

I downloaded the 1.42 archive and run 'make' but it compiled me : {18kmon, i8kctl, i8kfan), and did nothing with the smm.

I tried to compile the smm.c file separately 'gcc smm.c -o smm' but it shows:

```
htt@woodhost:~/Downloads/i8kutils$ gcc -Wall smm.c -o smm
smm.c: Assembler messages:
smm.c:50: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
smm.c:52: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
smm.c:58: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
smm.c:67: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
```

and when running with 'gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I. -o smm -m32 smm.c' it gives:

```
htt@woodhost:~/Downloads/i8kutils$ gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I. -o smm -m32 smm.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:27:0,
                 from smm.c:27:
/usr/include/features.h:364:25: fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <sys/cdefs.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
```

What is need to get the smm working?